# How to find the max hotspot of a matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search

I was given a matrix question on a technical assessment that revolved around the idea of finding the "Max Hotspot".

Areas of connected 1's represent a hotspot, and given a matrix we want to return the max hotspot. Similar to "Number of Islands" or "Word Search.

```
areamap = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 1, 1]]

areamap = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 1, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried using the 4 way DFS approach but had trouble creating/incrementing a variable that keeps track of the size of each hotspot. Any suggestions/help? Below is my attempt.

The idea of my algo is that every time we find a 1, we "evaporate" it to avoid traveling duplicates. For each 1 we evaporate, we incrementing the count of 1's. The count variable and the tmp list variable always print/return as empty.

```
class Solution:
    def hotSpots(self, area: List[int]):

        def evap(r, c, cnt):
            if r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= len(area) or c >= len(area[0]) or area[r][c] == "0":
                return

            cnt += 1
            area[r][c] = "0"
            evap(r, c + 1)
            evap(r, c - 1)
            evap(r + 1, c)
            evap(r - 1, c)
            return

        tmp = []
        for i in range(len(area)):
            for j in range(len(area[0])):
                count = 0
                if area[i][j] == "1":
                    evap(i, j, count)
                    tmp.append(count)
        return sum(max(tmp))
```

Comment: Does your code work? What exactly is the question / problem?

Comment: How could the result NOT be zero? you are not incrementing count anywhere in `hotSpots`. You might think you increment it in `evap`, but you are just incrementing the local copy without returning it. You need to return something from `evap`

Comment: Hi, I thought that the value of count could be changed by passing it into the function via a parameter. I now realize I was wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the code:

1. `evap` does not return any result and so `count` never gets assigned anything other than 0
2. You have an array of integers, but you check its elements against strings (`"0"` and `"1"`)

Solving those issues yields the following code, which outputs the result you want

```python
def hotSpots(area):

        def evap(r, c):
            if r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= len(area) or c >= len(area[0]) or area[r][c] == 0:
                return 0

            area[r][c] = 0
            return 1 + evap(r, c + 1) + evap(r, c - 1) + evap(r + 1, c) + evap(r - 1, c)

        tmp = []
        for i in range(len(area)):
            for j in range(len(area[0])):
                if area[i][j] == 1:
                    count = evap(i, j)
                    tmp.append(count)
        return sum(max(tmp))
```

Comment: Hey, I realize I made a lot of syntax errors in my drum up of the problem. I put it together by memory so I made a lot of mistakes myself.  When each function returns to its caller, it returns the value of " 1 + evap... + evap.." ? Still learning recursion so I'm curious as to how the return function at the bottom of evap retains its value.

Comment: Yes, it returns "1 + evap... + evap.." if the cell was a 1